# Is it possible to modify a FOR IN loop in this way?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table TMP(CodA) and this FOR loop:

```
FOR var IN (SELECT * FROM tmp) 
LOOP
   ....
END LOOP
```

If in the loop body I make an INSERT INTO TMP will it be considered and will the for continue to iterate?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: I can't test it at this moment

Comment: You can test it here - http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can insert into a table from which a cursor has been derived.  The read will not interfere with the subsequent write.

Here's an example:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP(CODA NUMBER);
INSERT INTO TMP VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO TMP VALUES (20);
COMMIT;
```

Then run the block:

```
DECLARE
  V_LOOP_COUNTER NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR VAR IN (SELECT * FROM TMP)
  LOOP
    V_LOOP_COUNTER := V_LOOP_COUNTER + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Loop iteration number: %s for coda-value: %d',TO_CHAR(V_LOOP_COUNTER),TO_CHAR(VAR.CODA)));
    INSERT INTO TMP VALUES (100 + VAR.CODA);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Edit for loop iterations**:
Looking at the `DBMS_OUTPUT`, the subsequent `INSERT`s do not interfere with the number of `LOOP` iterations:

```
Loop iteration number: 1 for coda-value: 10  
Loop iteration number: 2 for coda-value: 20  
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then after the procedure has completed, one can see the `INSERT`ed data:

```
SELECT * FROM TMP
ORDER BY CODA ASC;

      CODA
----------
        10
        20
       110
       120
```

Comment: So the for loop will iterate only 2 times (it take into consideration only the initial number of the rows) ?

Comment: Thanks @Diablo3000.  Sure it only iterates for the initial number of fetched rows.  The inserts in the loop will not alter the number of iterations.  I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Diablo3000 I've updated my answer to track loop-iterations.  Does this help clarify the looping?  Thanks